# Starnge INVALID_OPCODE exception when initialising IDT (64-bit kernel)

Tags: exception, assembly, crash, kernel

Here is the code that sets up the IDT.

```
global lngmd_start
extern kernel_main
extern gdt.data
section .text
bits 64
lngmd_start:
    mov ax, gdt.data
    mov ss, ax
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax
   call map_entries
   lidt [idt.pointer]
   sti
   ;call kernel_main
   ;int 0x00 
   jmp krnl_hlt


map_entries:
   mov rbx, idt
.map_exceptions:
   mov rdx, 0
   mov r8, exception_handler
   mov rcx, 32
   jmp .loop
.map_irqs_pic1:
   mov rdx, 1
   mov r8, isr_handler.pic1
   mov rcx, 8
   jmp .loop
.map_irqs_pic2:
   mov rdx, 2
   mov r8, isr_handler.pic2
   mov rcx, 8
.loop:
   mov rax, r8 
   mov word [rbx], ax
   shr rax, 16
   mov word [rbx + 6], ax
   shr rax, 16
   mov dword [rbx + 8], eax
   add rbx, 16
   dec rcx
   ;jmp krnl_hlt ; This works as intended and halts the kernel, printing "a2"
   jne .loop
   jmp krnl_hlt ; this is supposed to print "a2" then halt, but causes an INVALID_OPCODE (0x6 in QEMU debugger) exception. Removing this jump causes the code to hang with no exceptions.
   test rdx, rdx
   je .map_irqs_pic1
   
   dec rdx
   test rdx, rdx
   je .map_irqs_pic2
   ret
idt:
.exception_0:
        dw 0
        dw 0x8
        db 0
        db 10001110b
        dw 0
        dd 0
        dd 0
; --------------------------------
; exceptions 1 - 30
; --------------------------------
.exception_31:
        dw 0
        dw 0x8
        db 0
        db 10001110b
        dw 0
        dd 0
        dd 0
.irq_0:
   dw 0
   dw 0x8
   db 0
   db 10001110b
   dw 0
   dd 0
   dd 0
; --------------------------------
; irqs 1 - 14
; --------------------------------
.irq_15:
        dw 0
        dw 0x8
        db 0
        db 10001110b
        dw 0
        dd 0
        dd 0
.pointer:
        dw $ - idt - 1
        dq idt

exception_handler:
   jmp krnl_hlt

isr_handler:
.pic1:
   mov ax, 0x20
   out 0x20, ax
   iretq
.pic2:
   mov ax, 0x20
   out 0xa0, ax
   iretq

krnl_hlt:
    mov dword [0xb8000], 0x0c320c61
    abbc:
   hlt
   nop
    jmp abbc
```

I have spent the last 5 hours trying different ways to get this IDT working through many different methods, and I don't normally ask questions, but it seems I've hit a dead end. If I've missed any required info or asked a "bad question", let me know and I will try to make it better.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I fixed the issue. (If anyone wants to know how, the comments saying "exceptions 1-30" and "irqs 1-14" need to be replaced with actual code, I just had a brain freeze lol)